# Updating JavaScript Index

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I'm studying spring framework with maven, and when I try to make a change in my code I get this error "An internal error occurred during: "Updating JavaScript Index".
com/ibm/icu/util/StringTokenizer",

I tried following tutorials but due to my inexperience I didn't solve anything

Comment: Are you sure you are not using an outdated version of Eclipse? Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, copy it (Ctrl+C) and paste it into your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.